# SIGNALS and SLOTS in QT5

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt, user-interface, signals-slots

I've encountered a following issue:

I have a GUI element class and a Thread class. I would like to exchange signals between them. However it only works in one direction. I can successfuly send a signal from main GUI window to the thread. However when I want to send a signal from the thread to the process that calls the thread, but it doesn't work. Here is how I do it:

```
bool GfxMapItem::mapSwitch(int seqidx)
{
    ...
importMapThread_ = new ImportMapThread(sequence_->item(seqidx)); 
connect(GUI_UI->analExportButton,  SIGNAL(clicked()), importMapThread_, SLOT(interrupt1()), Qt::QueuedConnection); //<-- this one works perfectly 
connect(importMapThread_,  SIGNAL(progress(int)), this, SLOT(loadMap(int)), , Qt::QueuedConnection); // <-- this one unfortunatelly doesn't 
    ... 
}
```

The thread code is very simple and it only emits the signal (I've check that it works when I connect the thread with itself).

```
void ImportMapThread::run()
{
QLOGX("Running ImportMapThread..."); 
QLOGINC; 
emit this->progress(100); 

QLOGX("Stopping ImportMapThread..."); 
}
```

The thread header looks like the one below:

```
class ImportMapThread : public InterruptibleThread
{
Q_OBJECT

private: 
...

protected:
...

public:
ImportMapThread(SeqItem *p); 

signals: 
void progress(int value); 
void progressReset(int value); 

public slots: 
     virtual void interrupt1(); 
 void loadMap();  

protected: 
virtual void run(); 
};
```

And the class that calls that thread looks like this:

```
class GfxMapItem : public QObject, public QGraphicsPixmapItem
{
Q_OBJECT
...

signals:
void mouseOutside();
void mouseMove(const QPointF &pos);

private slots: 
void loadMap(int); 

protected:
...
};
```

Any ideas? Please, I've ran out of ideas.

Comment: What is `InterruptibleThread` , you should inherit from `QThread`

Comment: `InterruptibleThread` is inherited from `QThread`.

Comment: I see ImportMapThread contains custom slots. Be aware that those slots will run in the CALLING thread, not the new thread. From the [QThread docs](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qthread.html): _"It is important to remember that a QThread instance lives in the old thread that instantiated it, not in the new thread that calls run(). This means that all of QThread's queued slots will execute in the old thread. Thus, a developer who wishes to invoke slots in the new thread must use the worker-object approach; new slots should not be implemented directly into a subclassed QThread."_

Comment: I can't see the exact cause of the problem from your code snippets, but because you have code running in the wrong thread, it's possible that something is getting corrupted. If you want 2-way communications between threads, you need to use a Worker QObject (see the [QThread documentation](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qthread.html) for an example)

Comment: Actually this custom slot in the thread works, the problem is with the signal (not in the thread itself but in the process that runs the thread) or more likely with the slot `loadMap` that should be called by the signal from the thread. What do you mean by **code running in the wrong thread**?

Comment: I've tried with the examples provided in the documentation and still no luck.

Comment: What's calling `start()` on the `ImportMapThread` object? If it's being called in the `ImportMapThread()` ctor then the signal is likely being send before the connection is made so it's getting lost.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved! It turned out that only the GUI elements can communicate with the threads. The thread can be inherited from other type of the thread and there isn't any problem neither with the signals nor the slots. The problem was laying in the object GfxMapItem. For some reason it just couldn't handle normal communication.

Answer (score 0):

I believe, you should call exec in your run-implementation. Exec starts event-loop which should allow to send signals.

Take a look at:

> int QThread::exec() [protected] Enters the event loop and waits until
>   exit() is called, returning the value that was passed to exit(). The
>   value returned is 0 if exit() is called via quit(). It is necessary to
>   call this function to start event handling.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You need an event loop to RECEIVE signals, but you don't need one to SEND signals.